# How to change bootstrap icon's attributes using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-icons

I need -

1. To create a bootstrap icon (heart) when DOM content is loaded
2. When the icon is clicked, the heart icon fills with **red** (Here I use heart-fill icon)
3. Both of the icons to be **larger** than the *original*

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      var heart = document.createElement('i')
      heart.className = 'bi bi-heart'
      document.querySelector('#posts').append(heart)
      heart.onclick = function () {
        this.className = 'bi bi-heart-fill'
        this.setAttribute('fill', 'red')
      }
    } )
```

```html
<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css"></head>
<body><div id="posts"></div></body>
```

When I click the heart, it fills with black, not red. I also do not know how to make it larger by increasing the value of width and height. I saw other questions related to this, but none of them solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, since you used bootstrap icons and they are just working with the CSS [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) property, you do not have access to the `fill` property within them so it won't work as expected, alternatively, you should work with `color` and `font-size` property to achieve what you looking for.

In order to use it within javascript, You need to use `style` property and then access their attributes *(like `color` and `fontSize`)* within it. With the same solution, you can change the size of them with the `font-size` property.

Here is the final product of the above approaches:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var heart = document.createElement('i')
  heart.className = 'bi bi-heart'
  document.querySelector('#posts').append(heart)
  heart.onclick = function() {
    this.className = 'bi bi-heart-fill'
    this.style.color = 'red'
    this.style.fontSize = '24px'
  }
})
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="posts"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

The  tag's content can be treated as text, so you should use the "color" attribute to change the color, and the "font-size" to make it bigger, you can create a class with both this properties on css and asign the class to the element once the icon is clicked.

CSS:

```
.active { color: red; font-size: 24px }
```

JS:

```
(...)
heart.onclick = function() {
  this.classList.add('active')
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).